# Downloading and reading image from url

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

So what I am basically trying to do is to read any type of image from a url (png,jpg,etc...) and to be able to get its pure pixel data. So far I have this code.

```
  public static async Task<BitmapImage> DownloadImageFromWebsiteAsync(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
            {
                Stream imageStream = response.GetResponseStream();

                using (var result = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await imageStream.CopyToAsync(result);
                    byte[] array = result.ToArray();
                    return await ByteArrayToBitmapImage(array);
                }

            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static async Task<BitmapImage> ByteArrayToBitmapImage(byte[] byteArray)
    {
        var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

        var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        await stream.WriteAsync(byteArray.AsBuffer());
        stream.Seek(0);

        bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);

        return bitmapImage;
    }
```

Getting the pure byte[] as pixels doesn't work, because of the encoding such as jpeg. I was wondering is their any way to download a image from a url, decode it, and retrieve the pixel buffer. Help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You need to add `using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;` manually.

```
private async Task<byte[]> GetBytesFromImage(string URL)
{
    byte[] srcPixels;
    var uri = new Uri(URL);
    var streamRef = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(uri);

    using (IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType fileStream = await streamRef.OpenReadAsync())
    {
        BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(fileStream);
        PixelDataProvider pixelProvider = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();
        srcPixels = pixelProvider.DetachPixelData();
    }

    return srcPixels;
}
```